# SUMIFS where one of the conditions is at the top of table | Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

Sample: Two tables in one excel sheet.

***Criteria 1:***

```
ColumnA | ColumnB
Name    | Amount
John    | 3
Smith   | 2
John    | 6
```

***Criteria 2:***

```
Name    | Amount
John    | 10
Smith   | 20
```

I would like to perform => SUMIFS range is B:B and where the table name is "Criteria 1".

Note: there are a lot more names and criteria #.

Comment: So how have you used sumifs()? There are examples on here.

Comment: Then what result do you expect from your given sample data?

Comment: @Harun24HR I have edited the sample.  I would like to find `John's amount, but I would like to find the amount only under the "Criteria 1"`

In this case, the answer would be 9 (3 + 6; only from table under `Criteria 1`)

Comment: @MoLap refer the answers is that what you are looking for Formula used in cell B7` =SUMIFS(INDEX(Criteria_1,,2),INDEX(Criteria_1,,1),$A7)` Where `Criteria_1` is `='Blad (24)'!$A$2:$B$4`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried in this way? So what i have done is, i have created a **Defined Named Ranges** for **Criteria 1** and use the same within an **INDEX** Function so that gives a range which can be used within **SUMIFS** Function - **SUM_RANGE & CRITERIA RANGE**

So the formula used in Cell **B7**

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(Criteria_1,,2),INDEX(Criteria_1,,1),$A7)
```

[image: SUMIFS FUNCTION USING INDEX FUNCTION]

Where **Criteria_1** is **Defined Named Ranges**, how to create it, follow the steps

• Select the whole range i.e. in the image below, **A2:B4**

• Press **ALT F3** and in the **NAME BOX** write **Criteria_1**

This is one way to define a range -->

[image: NAME BOX]

The other way is select the range from Formulas Tab, Under **Defined Names Group** select **Define Name**. A new pop up shows --> Name it as **Criteria_1** and refers to already has been selected as the range required, and press OK

[image: DEFINED NAME RANGES]

Therefore as per the sample provided in my sheet the

```
Where Criteria_1 is ='Blad (24)'!$A$2:$B$4
```

Blad is sheet name so don't get confused!

Answer (score 0):

Formula in E2

```
 =SUMIFS($B$2:$B$100;$A$2:$A$100;D2)
```

[image]

Maybe good to convert your data to a standard table, so the formula will update when you add more data to it.

[image]

[image]